# Count number of rows for each type in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
A B C
1 4 Apple
2 5 Orange
3 6 Apple
1 4 Orange
2 4 Apple
3 4 Banana
```

I want to count each type of column C(if possible also plot it), ie output should be

```
Apple 3
Orange 2 
Banana 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just more to a new columns and paste the folloing in its header:

```
=query(H2:H,"select H, count(H) where H != '' group by H order by count(H) desc label H 'Fruit'", 0)
```

It is show something like your expection in new two columns beside the original data

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution already provided, you can make use of `UNIQUE` and `COUNTIF`.

1. Use `UNIQUE` in order to extract the names for each fruit from the `C` column

```
=UNIQUE(C1:C)
```

[image: after unique function]

2. Use `COUNTIF` within an `ARRAYFORMULA` in order to count the number of times each fruit is present in the `C` column and later drag it down the `E` column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(C1:C,D1))
```

[image: after the countif function]

#### Reference

- [UNIQUE Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198);
- [COUNTIF Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480).